# How to parse one field of an object using jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

Say I have an object and I want to find out the JSON value of one field.

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    @JsonProperty("MyBar")
    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

public enum Bar {
    BAR1(1), BAR2(2)

    private final int code;

    BAR(int code) {
        this.code = code
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the JSON value of `bar` field like

```
objectMapper.writeFieldAsString(foo, "bar")
objectMapper.valueToTree(foo).getWithOriginalFieldName("bar").asString()
```

Here is the real scenario of this case. I need to send my `Message` object as a JSON string. But before I send the message, I need to generate a signature of this message which needs partial fields of this message (and they need to be presented in JSON values not the original ones). So I have to pre-perform some jackson parsing logic in order to generate the signature (like handling @JsonFormat and Enum)

**Update 1**

There are lot of subclasses of `Message` and I use reflection to get the field which needs to be included in the message signature.

Comment: This tutorial uses @JsonProperty annotation to get specific fields http://javabycode.com/java-core/json-tutorial/jackson-json-annotation-example.html

Comment: can you not have `foo` as part of the POJO and have the `getter` return the formatted String message?  Or try using a specialised serialiser @JsonSerialize

Comment: @ScaryWombat The situation is there are lot of subclasses of Message and I cannot write a custom JsonSerializer for each of them.